# Removing rows limitation when making feature layer query using ArcGIS Python API

Tags: query, arcgis-python-api, spatio-temporal-data

I have a fairly big spatiotemporal dataset located at a server, which gets additional 1000 rows every 10 seconds for like two moths already. I am concerned to download and process this data day by day, but results of looking up in the dataset have only 50000 rows, it has data for about 10 minutes, but I need the whole day.

This is the code I used to get to the data:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from datetime import datetime as dt

date_bottom = str(dt.strptime('300621', '%d%m%y').date())
date_top = str(dt.strptime('010721', '%d%m%y').date())

gis = GIS('https://url-i-get-data-from.com/esri', username='usrname', password='psswrd')
#getting content by Service Item ID
item = gis.content.get('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
flayer = item.layers[0]

df = flayer.query(where=f"lastupdate BETWEEN DATE '{date_bottom}' AND DATE '{date_top}'").sdf
```

Does anybody know, what should I do in order to obtain all the rows, that match the condition? `return_all_records` option set to `True` does not help. RAM is not an issue in this case.